# How can I perform a map-reduce on filtered groups in RethinkDB?

Tags: javascript, sql, rethinkdb, reql

I have a RethinkDB table consisting of Robinhood Stock Orders.  The relevant fields are:

`side` (either `buy` or `sell`)
`state` (I'm only looking for `filled` orders)
`price` (Average USD price of the order)
`quantity` (Number of shares sold or purchased)

I'm simply trying to understand my all-time P/L on each stock in my Orders History.

I have the following working query which tells me the price of all SELL orders, grouped by stock symbol:

```
r.db('robinhood').table('orders').filter({side: 'sell', state: 'filled'})
 .map(function(order) { 
   return {
     cost: (order('price').coerceTo('number')).mul(order('quantity').coerceTo('number')),
     symbol: order('symbol')
   }
}).group('symbol').sum('cost')
```

This returns something like this:

```
[{"group":"AA","reduction":491},{"group":"AAPL","reduction":10589},{"group":"ABEO","reduction":7596.16},...]
```

Obviously, I can do the same query for the `BUY` side, which would tell me the total cost of all of my purchase orders (and then, theoretically, I could just subtract this from each of the previous `SELL` values).

**In short, how can I subtract the total value of `BUY` orders for each stock symbol from the total value of `SELL` orders for each stock symbol, using ONE ReQL query?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the inverse value of buy orders to your sum:

```
r.db('robinhood').table('orders').filter({state: 'filled'})
 .map(function(order) { 
   return {
     cost: order('price').coerceTo('number')
           .mul(order('quantity').coerceTo('number'))
           .mul(r.branch(order('side').eq('sell'), 1, -1)),
     symbol: order('symbol')
   }
}).group('symbol').sum('cost')
```